# VBA loop working but with Runtime Error at end

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am running a For Each loop to rename each worksheet in my workbook based on part of a string located in each respective worksheet. The code below 'works', meaning each worksheet is renamed, but then I get Runtime Error 1004 “Application-defined or Object-defined error”.

I've tried several fixes such as using 'ws' instead of 'sht', trying a cell reference instead of 'Range', and setting an Else in my If statement.

```
    For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If sht.Name <> "Control" Then
            sht.Name = Replace(sht.Range("A10"), "Using Restrictions of: Category Filter (Product) - ", "")
        End If
    Next
```

For a worksheet with the string "Using Restrictions of: Category Filter (Product) - Travel & Transport": 
1-I expect the sheet to be renamed 'Travel & Transport'
2-for each worksheet (except the sheet named 'Control') to be renamed relative to that sheet's string value in cell A10
3-for the sub to end without errors.
Actual: 1 and 2 successful but not 3

Answer (score 1):

Having executed your code, I would get `Runtime Error 1004 “Application-defined or Object-defined error` either if the new name of a worksheet ends up being blank or ends up exceeding the max number of characters it can hold.

That could happen if in some worksheet A10 is empty for example. In that case, the new name would end up being blank.

Another situation where this could occur is, if the string which you searching in order to replace is not identical to the one that is found in A10. For example you are searching for

```
"Using Restrictions of: Category Filter (Product) - "
```

but A10 for example is missing a space character:

```
"Using Restrictions of: Category Filter (Product)- Travel & Transport"
```

In this case the new name would end up being equal to A10 value which is exceeding the max characters.

Another possibility would be for `Control` worksheet's name to be spelled differently than how it's spelled in your `If-statement`. In this case all the sheets will be renamed and if A10 in `Control` is empty, then you'll get the `Runtime Error 1004`.

So my suggestion:

1. Make sure there are no hidden worksheets (right click on a sheet's tab and click Unhide)
2. Make sure that the worksheet you want to exclude from the loop is
   spelled exactly the same way as in your `If statement`
3. Make sure `"Control"` is the only worksheet that should be excluded from the loop
4. Make sure that this `"Using Restrictions of: Category Filter
   (Product) - "` is not misspelled in any of the worksheets that you
   want to rename.
5. Make sure that, whatever follows `"Using Restrictions of: Category Filter
   (Product) - "`, does not exceed the max number of characters that a worksheet's name can hold.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of testing, see if you can't do:

```
dim sht as worksheet, z as string, arr as variant, x as long
arr = Array("/", "\", "'", ",", "!", "@", "(", ")", "&", "-", "Using Restrictions of: Category Filter (Product) - ")
For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If sht.Name <> "Control" Then 
        z = sht.cells(10,1).value
        For x = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
            z = Replace(z, arr(x), "")
        Next x
        if len(z) > 0 then sht.Name = z
    End if
Next
```

I would be suspect that other symbols aren't showing up for your names.

The following error shows up when I have unnecessary symbols in the string the sheet name is intended to contain:

[image]

---

**Edit1:**

Added in a catch in case z = 0 so the sht name isn't changed